# JavaMail API not working

Tags: java, api, authentication, jakarta-mail

Since Stack Overflow does not let me answer my question I'll post here the solution: Google SMTP Server does not work in some countries, try using a VPN like TunelBear and then try again. It worked for me.

I'm trying to send a verification code from my application to the users email.

The problem is that besides that the email is not sent, the application keeps on running without throwing any errors or giving any response.

PS. I've enabled "Less Secure Apps" on my google account.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 * https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
 */
package SendEmail;

/**
 *
 * @author Naveen
 */
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
public class EmailSend {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            String host ="smtp.gmail.com" ;
            String user = "myemail@gmail.com";
            String pass = "mypassword";
            String to = "emailToSend@gmail.com";
            String from = "myemail@gmail.com";
            String subject = "This is confirmation number for your expertprogramming account. Please insert this number to activate your account.";
            String messageText = "Your Is Test Email :";
            boolean sessionDebug = false;

            Properties props = System.getProperties();

            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");

            java.security.Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
            Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, 
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
                            return new PasswordAuthentication("myEmail@gmail.com",
                                    "myPassword");
                        } } );



            mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
            msg.setSubject(subject); msg.setSentDate(new Date());
            msg.setText(messageText);

           Transport transport=mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
           transport.connect(host, user, pass);
           transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
           transport.close();
           System.out.println("message send successfully");
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you would like to give a shot with https://github.com/bbottema/simple-java-mail.

Comment: The `addProvider()` line hasn't been needed for fifteen years. What happens when you enable debug?

Comment: Just found the problem. JavaMail Api does not work in all countries. My country was excluded from the supported list. I was able though to send the email using a VPN.

Comment: I'm sure it's not just the JavaMail API that doesn't work.  It might be SMTP access to Gmail that doesn't work, no matter what API you might use to access it.  Or perhaps your ISP how some firewall that's preventing you from connecting to Gmail.  The [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) might provide more details on why you're not allowed to connect from your country.

Answer (score 0):

go to your google account security settings and do this:allow low secure apps :ON